# How can I fade out image?

Tags: beamer, graphics, animations

In a Beamer animation example I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\newcount\opaqueness 
\begin{frame} 
\animate<2-100> 
\animatevalue<1-100>{\opaqueness}{0}{100} 
\begin{colormixin}{\the\opaqueness!averagebackgroundcolor} 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image}
\end{center}
\end{colormixin} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this works for text only. How can I fade out the image?

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so that we can compile it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using TikZ to control the opacity. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcount\opaqueness
\begin{frame}
  \animate<2-100>
  \animatevalue<1-100>{\opaqueness}{0}{100}
  \begin{colormixin}{\the\opaqueness!averagebackgroundcolor}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [opacity=\opaqueness/100, scale=0.3] {\includegraphics{tiger}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      Tiger
    \end{center}
  \end{colormixin}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fading tiger]